# ArrayList passed over intent null pointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to send an arrayList of strings between two activities. The arrayList is clearly initialized in both activities, and then it is set equal to the arrayList pulled from getIntent.

Here is the first activity relevant code:

```
ArrayList elements = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize elements
```

elements is initialized, and then it is sent to addElement

```
addElementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent toAddElement = new Intent(NewRemote.this, addElement.class);
    toAddElement.putStringArrayListExtra("element_list", elements);
    startActivity(toAddElement);
    }
});
```

Then in addElement elements is initialized and then set equal to the arrayList pulled from the intent

```
ArrayList elements = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent getElements = getIntent();
elements = getElements.getStringArrayListExtra("element_list");
```

I am getting a null pointer on elements.add() when i call it slightly later

```
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            elements.add(selectedElement);
            Intent toNewRemote = new Intent(addElement.this, NewRemote.class);
            toNewRemote.putStringArrayListExtra(ELEMENT_LIST, elements); // send elements to newRemote
            startActivity(toNewRemote);
        }
    });
```

I am confused as to how I can get a null pointer when elements is clearly initialized, any help is appreciated.

please read all of this before marking as a duplicate, I have been looking for a solution to this issue for a couple of days and have not found a similar thread.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that the `elements` you're calling `add()` on in the second `Activity` is the one you're initializing? That is, are you sure you're not declaring a second `elements` as a field that's never being initialized?

Comment: Can you post the full log cat error?

Comment: Try developing an Android App using proper Java language in your Android Studio (which actually is just an IDE).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+arraylist+between+activity

Comment: You're missing the stacktrace and a [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 1):

There is something strange about your code.

```
ArrayList elements = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent getElements = getIntent();
elements = getElements.getStringArrayListExtra("element_list");
....
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        elements.add(selectedElement);
        Intent toNewRemote = new Intent(addElement.this, NewRemote.class);
        toNewRemote.putStringArrayListExtra(ELEMENT_LIST, elements); // send elements to newRemote
        startActivity(toNewRemote);
    }
});
```

Here you used `elements` in an inner function. but you did not define it as final !
I guess the`elements` inside your `onClick` function refer to another array which you did not initialize.

Comment: That is exactly why NullPointerException happen! He have an elements array in its class which never get initilized. @AbdulWaheed

Comment: did you try just removing final modifier and experienced any exception? What i have observed it gives compile time error rather throwing exception.

Comment: If there is a field of the same name, the code will compile

Comment: This makes sense as potentially being the problem, but I checked a couple different ways, and it doesn't seem to be the issue. I changed the variable name, just to make sure that there is no other arrayList, and it gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `final` declare `elements` as `global`.

**Try this:**

```
ArrayList elements;
.......
.................

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    elements = new ArrayList<String>();

    Intent getElements = getIntent();
    elements = getElements.getStringArrayListExtra("element_list");

    ........ 
    .................

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            elements.add(selectedElement);
            Intent toNewRemote = new Intent(addElement.this, NewRemote.class);
            toNewRemote.putStringArrayListExtra(ELEMENT_LIST, elements); // send elements to newRemote
            startActivity(toNewRemote);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I gave this a try and it didn't seem to work. really not sure where this issue is coming from!

Answer (score -1):

First of you don't need to initialize your ArrayList as you doing

```
ArrayList elements = new ArrayList<String>();
```

because it will be referenced by that list you are receiving via intent as

```
elements = getElements.getStringArrayListExtra("element_list");
```

Try below code that is working and tested as well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Intent getElements = getIntent();
    final ArrayList elements = getElements.getStringArrayListExtra("element_list");

    findViewById(R.id.btn_add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            elements.add("selected element");
            Intent toNewRemote = new Intent(addElement.this, NewRemote.class);
            toNewRemote.putStringArrayListExtra(ELEMENT_LIST, elements); // send elements to newRemote
            startActivity(toNewRemote);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i gave this a try and no such luck =/ i am really lost as to why this is happening